# Unity- have pile of objects but they want to explode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, physics, collider

Ok, Im just trying to have a SETTLED pile of objects like this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjem72Awa3eAhWKEZAKHbHMCBcQwqsBMAB6BAgGEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPJBPCnuaqIo&usg=AOvVaw1ewMypDbMyIV-qz8LZoo2e

But with gravity enable rigid bodies, so the user can pick them up/drop them in game. Ive done what the video did, and have the pile of objects great in play mode once settled, but if I copy the settled pile, don't remove the rigid bodies and press play, they explosively collide with each other again.

I want to start my game WITH the settled pile, no explosion. What can I do to get this and still have objects movable?

Is there a way to reduce the "explosive" nature of the collision?

Comment: The reason for the tutorial you linked is to show how to make object look positioned on the floor. That's really it. Why are you still trying to move the object after they are relaxed?

Comment: Check if you are applying any force on Start()

Comment: @programmer in the video he says you can leave the rigid bodies  so the items are moveable. that is what OP wants. this is a collider problem, i would assume he paused it and copied there state before they completely settled, meaning some of the colliders were colliding at the time, so when play starts, they explode outward. he needs to check and double check his colliders to make sure they are accurate, and he needs to drop the pile again and let it settle before he copies it. if he then moves and item before copying he needs to hit play and make sure it settles, before copying the pile.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens you were right, did not let it settle fully

Comment: glad to help. issues fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help. I had a similar behaviour of objects colliding with each other explosively.

The cause: I had a sphere collider which wasn't the right type of collider for this use case.

The solution:  By changing to a box collider they rested against one another until the player collided with them.

If you have a box collider it makes the objects behave like a box which has flat sides.

In my case they were rocks and even in an oblong shape they exploded initially without the box collider.

However, later I found that some round objects with sphere colliders didn't do this when stacked.So I think it's a mixture of placement and what type of collider suits the shape of the object. Those are my deductions.